# Странное поведение NPM

Tags: npm

Вопрос имеет консультационный характер. Хочу понять, почему оно так, а не иначе.

Итак, иду и ставлю typescript:

```
>npm install typescript --save
`-- typescript@2.0.10
```

Установленная версия - это stable версия typescript, которая на данный момент 2.0.10.

Однако, я знаю, что есть RC с версией [2.1.1](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/releases). Посмотрим, что сделает npm update:

```
>npm update typescript
`-- typescript@2.1.1
```

Ага, понятно. Update выполнил обновление до RC и теперь у меня typescript версии 2.1.1.

Теперь я хочу посмотреть на outdated пакеты, что я вижу?

```
>npm outdated
Package     Current  Wanted  Latest  Location
typescript    2.1.1   2.1.1  2.0.10  folder
```

Здесь возникают вопросы:

1. Почему 2.1.1 считается outdated? Из описания [npm update](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/outdated) может быть и можно подумать, что раз установленная версия != latest, то пакет считается outdated, но это всё равно не сказано "черным по-белому"
2. Почему npm update устанавливает, в таком случае, пакеты, которые могут быть RC? А если я напишу скрипт, который будет периодически обновлять пакеты? - то я в какой-то момент могу получить не слишком безопасную систему, имея новые НЕ stable пакеты
3. Ну и вообще странно то, что current может быть больше, чем latest. Даже если ставится RC, то хотелось бы иметь какое-нибудь уведомление об этом при отображении списка пакетов.